# Testing Spring Rest Endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, mockmvc

I am attempting to run tests on my controller when I attempt my findbyid test I keep getting a 404 and I'm not sure why.

This is the method from my controller

```
 @CrossOrigin
@GetMapping(path="/movie/{id}")
public @ResponseBody Movies getMovie(@PathVariable Integer id){
    return moviesRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Movie not found"
    ) );
}
```

And this is the test.

```
@Test
void getSingleMovie() throws Exception{
    Movies movies = new Movies(1, "Star Wars", "A New Hope");
    when(moviesController.getMovie(1)).thenReturn(movies);
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/movies/1")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    ).andReturn();
    Mockito.verify(moviesRepository).findAllById(Collections.singleton(1));
```

The output from my stacktrace has the following in it...

```
    MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = Movies not found
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
    java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' expected:<*> but was:<null>
    Expected :*
    Actual   :null
```

Comment: Does the controller have a request mapping?

Comment: It has get mapping for that specific method.

Comment: Your method is mapped with `/movie/{id}`, but in the test you are using `/movies/1` (it has the excess character `s`).

Comment: Excess character?

Comment: Yes, try to change the URL in the test on `/movie/1`. I.e. `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/movie/1")`.

Comment: I'm confused. I already have that line on this 

MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/movies/1")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

When I try to put it on this

when(moviesController.getMovie(1)).thenReturn(movies);

I get the following
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(movieweb.movies.models.Movies)'

Comment: The `/movies/1` url is wrong, change it on `/movie/1`.

Comment: Jeez, can't believe I missed that. 

However, I still get the 404 error but now in my stacktrace I get this.....

Wanted but not invoked:
moviesRepository bean.findAllById([1]);
-> at movieweb.movies.MovieApplicationTests.getSingleMovie(MovieApplicationTests.java:78)

Comment: This is because of the controller calls the `findById` method, but in the test you are checking that was called the `findAllById` repository method.

Comment: BOOM test passed, so I wasn't that far off just a few oversights in the code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your test method a little bit
as shown below. some correction are needed

```
@Test
void getSingleMovie() throws Exception{
    Movies movies = new Movies(1, "Star Wars", "A New Hope");
    when(moviesRepository.findById(Mockito.eq(1))).thenReturn(Optional.of(movies));
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/movie/1")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    ).andReturn();
    Mockito.verify(moviesRepository).findById(Mockito.eq(1));
```